# Failed to find build tools revision 29.0.2 - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, error-handling

Recently I encountered this issue after updating my android studio to the latest version 4.0.

Answer (score 33):

I recently solved this problem

Open Android Studio

1. Click on **`File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK`**
2. Click on **`SDK Tools`**
3. Under that Click on **`Android SDK Build Tools`**
4. Click on **`Show package Details`** at the bottom right corner
5. Now find **`29.0.2`**
6. Click on that
7. Click on **`Apply`** > (Wait until download completion) > **`Finish`** > **`Ok`**

Answer (score 7):

1. Click Open Project Structure icon  or use keyboard shortcut directly (shift+ctrl+alt+s)

[image: Project Structure]

2. Click Modules

[image: Modules]

3. Select the properties option

[image: properties]

4. choose to download and install the various configurations
   make sure the Build Tools version and the compiled sdk version are consistent

[image: download and install]

5. Re-run the project

Answer (score 2):

So tried all the solutions but got stuck at one point, couldn't locate "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools" this path.

The way around this is to close the current project you're working on..
Click "Configure" at the bottom right of Android studio
Click 'SDK manager"
Click 'SDK tools"
Tick 'Show Package Details"
look for the corresponding build-tools, in my case, 29.0.2
Click apply

it should download the build tool>>> then rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

1. download last version platform-tools this link https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
2. copy platform-tools to sdk\platform-tools
3. rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Please note that 'platform-tools' differs from 'build-tools'.
Here the topic is **'build-tools'** so here's what worked for my case:
what you need to do is simply download required
'build-tools' from somewhere like: https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools
then copy the downloaded folder somewhere like(if you use Windows): C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools,
then change the downloaded file name to the version of build tool(for this question the version is 29.0.2).
Re-build and re-run your project.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.**

So, probably you specified build tool version explicitly in the build file. Just remove `buildToolsVersion = "x.y.z"` from your *build.gradle* script.

If, for some reason, you need that specific revision, follow [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66560409/8583692).