# Android Studio property does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, version

I had a basic tic-tac-toe android application, it was found in the default directory, which is C: \ Users \ Surface \ AndroidStudioProjects in windows, but i wanted to relocate that. After the relocation, I got an error: specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.
I read about it a lot, and i found a solution, wehere I downgraded the versions (in build.gradle: 4.1.2 -> 4.0.2, in gradle-wrapper.properties: 6.5 -> 6.4.1).
After all that i realized, if I make a new project in the default directory, it works just fine with the newer version, but in a different directory, it's need to be changed.
Does anyone know if i am doing something wrong, or i just found a bug, and if there is any solution besides the version downgrade.

Thanks in advance

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip
```

Comment: Try right click on the folder and select copy.

Comment: Then paste it into the new location.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/64928273/12858662